# Expect script: wait for completion

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm using an expect script to connect to a windows machine and execute an ant script. After completion I want to delete a file and log out. The execution of the ant script takes almost 30 seconds, so I added a "sleep 40" to the expect script. But what if the execution time will be much longer? Is there a way to let the expect script wait without using the sleep command?

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to answer you with that little information. How about showing the current script?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ofcourse you can, why don't you see what is outputed to the screen after the script has finished ?
For example:

```
expect "ssh:/C/remoteWindows/myfolderwithantscript/$"
send "rm a_file.txt"
```

where **ssh:/C/remoteWindows/myfolderwithantscript/** is the text you get after the scipt finishes, on a linux machine is something like this: /home/alex/Documents$ for example, and then you send the 'rm' command to remove the file.

This is what I do so as to upload a file to an ftp server. I just do a

```
expect "sftp>"
```

and then proceed to the next steps.